# Move all files from a directory tree to another directory. Rename if repeated names

Tags: python, file, rename, move, shutil

I need to get all the files in a given directory tree (folder named Temp and subdirectories with more subdirectories and files...) encrypt them and move everything to a unique directory (folder named Temp2 with no subdirectories). If there are repeated names, I want to change name to, let's say, text.txt --> text(1).txt and continue moving that renamed file.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
bufferSize = 64 * 1024
password1 = 'password'

print('\n> Beginning recursive encryption...\n\n')
for archivo in glob.glob(sourcePath + '\\**\*', recursive=True):
   fullPath = os.path.join(sourcePath, archivo)
   fullNewf = os.path.join(destinationPath, archivo + '.aes')

   if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
      print('>>> Original: \t' + fullPath + '')
      print('>>> Encrypted: \t' + fullNewf + '\n')
      pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(fullPath, fullNewf, password1, bufferSize)
      shutil.move(fullPath + '.aes', destinationPath)
```

It encrypts just fine and proceeds to move encrypted files. The problem is that when it finds and tries to move a file with the an existing name, it gives me an error:

> shutil.Error: Destination path
>   'E:\AAA\Folder\Folder\Temp2\Text.txt.aes' already exists

So I need to know how to rename files with repeated names in the proccess of moving them and then move them, but don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def make_unique_filename(file_path):
    duplicate_nr = 0
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    while os.path.exists(file_path):
        duplicate_nr += 1
        file_path = f'{base}({duplicate_nr}){extension}'

    return file_path
```

and then

```
os.rename(src_file_path, make_unique_filename(dest_file_path))
```

shutil.move moves to a directory destination.

It is easier to use os.rename.
It moves a file to a new destination file. The new destination dir file should be unique, wihich you can do with make_unique_filename.

This code is working for me now. There was another problem with your os.path.join. It is not necessary. glob.glob already returns a full path.

```
import pyAesCrypt
import os
import glob

sourcePath = r'E:\test aes\src'
destinationPath = r'E:\test aes\dst'

bufferSize = 64 * 1024
password1 = 'password'

def make_unique_filename(file_path):
    duplicate_nr = 0
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    while os.path.exists(file_path):
        duplicate_nr += 1
        file_path = f'{base}({duplicate_nr}){extension}'

   return file_path


for archivo in glob.glob(sourcePath + '\\**\*', recursive=True):
    fullPath = archivo
    fullNewf = archivo + '.aes'

    if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
        print('>>> Original: \t' + fullPath + '')
        print('>>> Encrypted: \t' + fullNewf + '\n')
        pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(fullPath, fullNewf, password1, bufferSize)

        destination_file_path = os.path.join(destinationPath, os.path.split(fullNewf)[1])
        destination_file_path = make_unique_filename(destination_file_path)
        print(destination_file_path)
        os.rename(fullNewf, destination_file_path)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I tried the code but it doesn't do what I want. It copies, encrypts and renames EVERY FILE adding (1), and doesn't move them to the destinationPath.

Comment: Paste the code you have now in your question above and I will have a look.

Comment: My  above code is working now. There was a problem/confusion about the pathes you use. For clarity, and to print it,  I have split out the making of destination_file_path.